# Attributes of properties in MetadataType are ignored by EntLib Validation

Tags: c#, .net, validation, enterprise-library, metadatatype

It's an EntLib-Validator-issue again. I'm playing with EntLib 5.0 in C# and .Net 4.0 on XP pro.

I have some business objects (partial classes) generated by T4 templates. So I decided to put their validation attributes in buddy-classes by using `MetadataTypeAttribute` as definitely recommended by the documentation of entLib 5.0 ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664465%28PandP.50%29.aspx)).
But the `Validator` object I get from the ValidatorFactory doesn't know about the validation attributes, defined in the metadata-class.

The business object is defined like this:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(PatientMetadata))]
public partial class Patient
{
    private string _Name;
    private int _DiagnosisCount;

    public int DiagnosisCount
    {
        get
        {
            return _DiagnosisCount;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != _DiagnosisCount)
            {
                _DiagnosisCount = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != _Name)
            {
                _Name = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the metadata class like this, according to documentation:

```
public class PatientMetadata
{
    [RangeValidator(4)]
    public int DiagnosisCount { get; set; }

    [StringLengthValidator(64, ErrorMessage = "Name must not exceed 64 chars.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If I know try to do validation this way:

```
    var factory = ValidationFactory.DefaultCompositeValidatorFactory;
    var validator = factory.CreateValidator<Patient>();
```

...then watching into `validator` (during debugging) already says, that it's just an `AndCompositeValidator` without any children validators.
Again, if I put the validation attributes right in the `Patient` class, it works perfectly.

By now, I have no real idea, what I'm missing here, since I think doing everything according to the docs.

Thanks in advance to you guys!

Answer (score 1):

The property names of the metadata class must match the property names of the main class.

In your case your metadata class should look like:

```
public class PatientMetadata
{
    [RangeValidator(0, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, 10, RangeBoundaryType.Ignore)]
    public int DiagnosisCount { get; set; }

    [StringLengthValidator(6, ErrorMessage = "Name must not exceed 6 chars.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Also, the docs indicate the accepted approach is to declare all return types as `object`.  However, the docs also talk about using properties but in their example use fields so take it under advisement.  :)

Comment: You're right, but that naming problem was just the case in my example here, not in my application itself. But I meanwhile figured out, that it is essential, to use **properties** in the metadata class, if I have properties in the original class. As you said, they use fields in the docs, what is kind of misleading, I think. The datatype is irrelevant, they suggest to use object at all, but you're still able to use the corresponding types just if you want to.